# What's the International Youth Travel Card (IYTC)?

Tags: identity-cards

Osprey is "giving away" International Youth Travel Cards (IYTC) with their bags at the moment.

The only details they give is that it gives some discounts for food, drink, travel and accommodation.

What exactly is the IYTC and what does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a version of the ISIC student discount card for under 30s who aren't students.

> The International Youth Travel Card (IYTC) is available to individuals aged 31 years old or younger, who are not fulltime students. The IYTC card carries many of the same benefits and discounts as the ISIC card. The IYTC card is a valuable tool particularly if you are travelling abroad.
>
> The IYTC card is valid for one year from the date of issue. You need to apply for the IYTC card before your 30th birthday in order to be eligible for the card.

The [ISIC](https://www.isic.org/discounts/) website has a page detailing all the available discounts...